# correct usage of 'in spite of' instead of 'although'

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, sentence

It is difficult to figure out how to alter the word *although* for a case like below as in my report there are many *although*.. so I am looking for an alternative like *in spite of*

> *Although* the merging step increased the incorrect growth of the water over the grasslands, the merging didn't affect the classified tree clusters because the algorithm didn't lose any candidates.

I have altered it as;

> *In spite of* the incorrect growth of the water over the grasslands by the merging step, the merging didn't affect the classified tree clusters because the algorithm didn't lose any candidates.

I am not very sure whether my 2nd sentence is correct. would it be ok?

Comment: This is a thesaurus question. Have you checked out "although" on [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/although?s=b)? There are many alternatives on that page. There are other grammatical problems with your sentence. "affect for the classified" should be "affect the classified" and "as the algorithm doesn't lost any" should be "because the algorithm {doesn't / didn't} lose any". Please edit your question, look at the thesaurus and select some alternative expressions, and then rephrase your question when you have a few specific questions about which alternative is best.

Comment: @ Bill Franke: thanks for the corrections... i have added alternative sentence and altered the post as well.

Comment: niro, your second sentence still has a number of significant fluency errors. *Grasslands* is one word; 'didn't lost' is ungrammatical; "by merging step" seems to be missing an article or determiner ("by *(the)/(this)* merging step"); and the referent of 'it' is unclear in "it didn't affect" (perhaps should be "*(the step)/(this)* didn't affect").

Comment: I agree with Mark that your new sentence has fluency errors. Another problem with it is that in addition to replacing "although", you've changed the syntax of the sentence. That complicates the question. I'll answer the question about replacing "although" with a synonymous expression.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: sorry, I have corrected as much

Comment: The sentence looks better now.  I think it is possible that you have used the wrong worth 'growth'. Water is not usually thought of as capable of growing, but I admit I do not know the scientific context. Perhaps you mean the *spread* or the *rise*.

I will let @BillFranke address the  'although'.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I thought first sentence should be change if I use in spite of, and found some mistakes in second part (sorry for it) and corrected it

Comment: Not only is water incapable of growing, it's even more unfathomable to imagine "incorrect growth". Growth is growth. It may be mis-shaped etc, but growth is not "incorrect". Also a slight issue with wording like "merging step" being used as an actor but it's really a passive non-actor or otherwise the "step" is not causal; instead it's some action or reaction that is causal. Weak constructs like that make it harder to understand what is actually going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace "although" with a number of expressions that are synonymous without significantly changing the syntax of your sentence as you did in sentence 2. Here are some examples:

> *Even though* the merging step increased the incorrect growth of the water over the grasslands, the merging didn't affect the classified tree clusters because the algorithm didn't lose any candidates.

or

> *Despite the merging step's having* increased the incorrect growth of the water over the grasslands, the merging didn't affect the classified tree clusters because the algorithm didn't lose any candidates.

or

> *The merging step's having increased the incorrect growth of the water over the grasslands notwithstanding*, the merging didn't affect the classified tree clusters because the algorithm didn't lose any candidates.

There are other problems with the sentence, though. It sounds awkward to me. Maybe the phrase "incorrect growth of the water" should be changed to "flow of water", and maybe "the merging" should be changed to "the merge". I can imagine some scenarios in which irrigation water or flood waters merged and inundated grasslands, but I don't really know what this sentence is talking about, so it's difficult for me to come up with any better alternatives. I don't much like the three I've suggested, but editing someone else's writing without fully understanding what they want to say is usually somewhere between difficult and impossible.